# Test Cases For Flux

Tags: java, spring

```
public static CommandResponse mappedResponse(EventObjectResponse eventObjectResponse) {
    Flux<Tuple2<ResponseEventEntity, CommandMetadata>> dataMappedFlux = eventObjectResponse
            .getFluxResponseEventEntity().map(t -> {
                try {
                    return mappingMetaData(t);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    log.error(e.getMessage());
                    throw new ErrorCodeException(ErrorCodes.UNEXPECTED_EXCEPTION,
                            new Exception("error accoured in the mappingMetaData"));
                }
            })
            .onErrorMap(e -> new ErrorCodeException(ErrorCodes.UNEXPECTED_EXCEPTION,
                    new Exception("event meta data dataMappedFlux error "+e.getMessage())))
            .doOnError(e -> log.error(e.getMessage()));
    CommandResponse commandResponse = new CommandResponse();
    commandResponse.setFluxwithmetadata(dataMappedFlux);
    commandResponse.setPagingToken(
            StringUtils.isNotEmpty(eventObjectResponse.getPagingToken()) ? eventObjectResponse.getPagingToken()
                    : null);
    return commandResponse;
}


public static Tuple2<ResponseEventEntity, CommandMetadata> mappingMetaData(ResponseEventEntity r) throws Exception  {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    CommandMetadata commandMetadata = new CommandMetadata();
    if(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(r.getEventMetadata())) {
        String eventMetadata = r.getEventMetadata().startsWith("v1:")? r.getEventMetadata().substring(3): r.getEventMetadata();
        CommandMetadata eventMetadatamodel = mapper.readValue(eventMetadata, CommandMetadata.class);
        if(ObjectUtils.isNotEmpty(eventMetadatamodel)) {
        commandMetadata.setSourceAppId(eventMetadatamodel.getSourceAppId());
        commandMetadata.setClientAppId(eventMetadatamodel.getClientAppId());
        commandMetadata.setRequestedByAgent(eventMetadatamodel.getRequestedByAgent());
        if(ObjectUtils.isNotEmpty(commandMetadata.getProperties())) {
            commandMetadata.setProperties(eventMetadatamodel.getProperties());
        }
    }
    }
    return Tuples.of(r, commandMetadata);
}
```

Need to cover 100% of this test cases
We need for this to code junits so that we can be sure about the code that nothing is getting missed
What can be done best to resolve this issue.

Comment: So... write tests?

Comment: Write tests until all the code is covered? Or are you expecting someone here to write the tests for you?